# SoapHeader Value missing in ASP.NET 3.5 Web Service

Tags: web-services, asmx, soapheader

I have created a custom SOAPHeader and Service with methods. While I was trying to consume the service, I was able to create the SOAPHeader and assign its property. But the proxy(SOAPClient) is missing the HeaderValue property.
My web method is expecting this Header as a parameter instead of property of the proxy.

---

Client Proxy:

```
MyServiceSoapClient client = new MyServiceSoapClient();
AuthHeader header = new AuthHeader();
header.UserName = "test";

client.MyMethod(header, value);
```

I want to set the header in "client" not send as parameter.

Comment: You won't get any help without detail.

Comment: How about showing the server-side?

Comment: In server side the header works.

Answer (score 1):

In your web service client, be sure to add a Web Reference and not a Service Reference (WCF service.) This will remove the soap header parameter from each call and add the SoapHeaderValue property you're looking for.